# Transmitting video using Raspberry Pi Zero (and an RF transmitter)

Tags: pi-zero, nrf24l01

I am working on a project (building a small satellite, a *CanSat*) that requires me to capture and send video, wirelessly, sort of like an FPV set up.

But, it has some limitations: the whole video capturing and transmitting set up **has** to be very **small** and **light weight** and transmit to a range of about 200-300 metres.

I was thinking of using something like an nrf24l01+ 2.4Ghz tranceiver, as they are light weight and don't consume much power. But, I'm not sure I could send, and receive, video through that (I've read some people saying they aren't very good for that). Are there better options? Which ones? How do they work?

Comment: I can't see much actual relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: 300 meters sounds like an awfully low altitude for a satellite :)